# change a variable length argument list to fixed size in inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, variadic-functions

## Requirements

1. I need a polymorphic method.
2. Argument lists in subclasses are not the same size.
3. Arguments in subclass may be from different subtypes and I would like the compiler to perform type checking in subclasses regarding determined subtype;

So list or array is not suitable as argument. Because they do not force size, or exact subtype!

## More details and example

[The codes are for illustration, and you may find compile errors in them.]

### First case

I need a base class with a method that accepts variable length argument list. This allows me to have a general class. For example:

```
abstract class baseClass{
    public abstract void serialize(Object... data);
}
```

Now I want to create some subclasses that are specific, so I need to have fixed size argument list in subclasses. For example something like this (but this syntax is wrong!) :

```
class subClass1 extends baseClass{
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object data1){
        //method body...
    }
}
class subClass2 extends baseClass{
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object data1, Object data2){
        //method body...
    }
}
```

How should I write the subclasses?

### Second case

In other case, my subclass would like to define the type of arguments explicitly (Because this will allow compile time checking). For example:

```
class subClass3 extends baseClass{
    @Override
    public void serialize(int data1){
        //method body...
    }
}
class subClass4 extends baseClass{
    @Override
    public void serialize(int data1, double data2, String data3){
        //method body...
    }
}
```

How should I write this one?

Answer (score 0):

One important rule of overriding...

> 1. The argument list should be exactly the same as that of the overridden
>      method.

refer for other rules 
 http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_overriding.htm

Alternatively you can use overloading. Something like the code below, can be present in the subclass

```
    void test(Object data) {
// some logic here
        super.test(data);
    }
```

I dont know what your requirements are, but I would probably make the super class method "parameterized" so that sub classes can provide concrete implementations.

==================== EDITED =====================================
I dont know your usecase. But based on the post, following is the solution that I could think of. Please check if this works.

```
abstract class baseClass<T>{
    public abstract void serialize(T... data);
}
class subClass1 extends baseClass <String>{
    @Override
    public void serialize(String... data) {
        if(data.length>1)throw new IllegalArgumentException("Accepts only single string");
    }
}
class subClass2 extends baseClass<Integer>{
    @Override
    public void serialize(Integer... data) {
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    baseClass<String> sc1 = new subClass1();
    sc1.serialize("test");

    baseClass<Integer> sc2 = new subClass2();
    sc2.serialize(1,2);
}
```

Comment: 1) I know the rule. 2) Please refer to the "Requirements" in the question.

Comment: I have edited my post with a suggestion. Please check if that helps. Else we need to wait for others to provide new ideas.

Comment: This is a good try, but has 2 shortcomings: 1) what if arguments have different types in one subclass? 2) I prefer compile time checking, rather run time. Of course we can propose some other good run time solutions!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with serialized data before, but could you do something like this:

```
public abstract void serialize(Object[] data)
{
    for(Object obj : data)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

-Kaz

Comment: No, because: 1) Object[] is just as same as Object... 2) I want compile time type checking. this is important!

Comment: The above would be the variable length bit, then the subclass has to implement all the members of the superclass.

Comment: Whereas your Constructors will be quite different between base class and subclass.

Would it not be easier to have single to have a single 'object data1' in the super then extend it with more 'object data1, object data2'. 

What is the benefit of variable length if the subclasses are known extensions?

Comment: "What is the benefit of variable length if the subclasses are known extensions?" --> because subclasses has different arguments, but the method title should be implemented in all of them. so I want to force them to implement the method by the superclass.

Comment: My understanding is that the superclass (your baseClass) contains members that are common to all subclasses, and that the subclasses *extend* those present in the superclass. 

The way you are thinking with the variable constructor, all subclasses would inherit a variable number of Object members, is that the case? You would have to super(Object... data) for that to work but it doesn't really help. 

Would it be possible to have multiple superclass constructor with (if you know what they would be) different lengths of arguments, although that largely defeats the purpose.